# PHP & MySQL Password Question

Tags: php, mysql

How can I add a salt to my current hash password when a user registers. And how should I store to my password in My MySQL database?

Here is my PHP code so far.

```
if ($_POST['password1'] == $_POST['password2']) {
    $sha512 = hash('sha512', $_POST['password1']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $purifier->purify(strip_tags($sha512)));
} else {
    $password = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "how to store" part? Do you mean how to insert it into the database, or what database schema you need?

Comment: I was wondering if there was any special way needed to insert it into the MySQL database?

Comment: It's just a string, handle it like any other text.

Answer (score 2):

```
$salt = 'my-secret-salt-92h3nc29378ry293';

...

$sha512 = hash('sha512', $salt . $_POST['password1']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $sha512);
```

To salt a password you simply concatenate it with another string (the salt) before hashing it. You also don't need to purify and exorcize the hashed password like you did, a hash won't contain anything bad.

You can use one salt for all passwords, which you should store somewhere centrally in your app. Alternatively, create a random salt for each password and save it alongside the hashed password in the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_POST['password1'] == $_POST['password2']) {
    $sha512 = hash('sha512', $_POST['password1']."salt"); //<--------------------
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $purifier->purify(strip_tags($sha512)));
} else {
    $password = NULL;
}
// vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
$user = $_POST['user'];
$db = mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'password');
mysql_select_db('database', $db);
mysql_query("UPDATES user_table SET pass=$password WHERE user=$user");
mysql_close($db);
```

Comment: @snag A "salt" just refers to anything that is added before or after the password prior to being hashed, giving it a different hashed string. In this case I used the string "salt" for my salt. You can use anything you want, but make sure it's a salt that you can use again when comparing the password or you'll never be able to log in! (setting a constant salt is usually recommended. Some people use the username or other parameters as a salt)

Answer (score 0):

You can use algortithms like:

`sha512($password.$salt)` or `sha512(sha512($password.$salt)` It's up to you how the salt is generated, as long as its being stored alongside with the password hash in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I like to store the salt with the password hash in the database and compute it like this:

```
$salt = "Su0";
$password = "mypassword0111";
$hash = md5(md5($password) . $salt);
```

Then when you login a user:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE username = '...
//do db lookup
$hash = md5(md5($password_from_user_login) . $salt_from_db);
if($hash = $hash_from_db) {
  $userloggedin = true;
}
```

Or something like that